# sudospawner not detected by jupyterhub

Tags: jupyter, jupyterhub

I have installed sudospawner for jupyterhub with: 
`sudo pip3 install sudospawner`
Then followed the instructions to setup the sudoers and added to my jupyterhub_config.py:

```
c.JupyterHub.spawner_class = 'sudospawner.SudoSpawner'
c.SudoSpawner.sudospawner_path = '/usr/local/bin/sudospawner'
```

However, it seems that the jupyterhub that I installed does not detect it since when I start the hub:

```
[C 2017-11-02 15:37:07.028 JupyterHub application:90] Bad config encountered during initialization:
[C 2017-11-02 15:37:07.029 JupyterHub application:91] The 'spawner_class' trait of <jupyterhub.app.JupyterHub object at 0x7f3fa0e24080> instance must be a type, but 'sudospawner.SudoSpawner' could not be imported
```

(ends with `'sudospawner.SudoSpawner' could not be imported`)

the version of jupyter hub is 0.8.0

It seems that I am missing something in the install or integration of sudospawner.

Any ideas ? 
Thx

Answer (score 0):

If you can install git and run this command with same configuration -

```
sudo pip3 install git+https://github.com/jupyter/sudospawner
```